# How to deploy python app to Azure Function

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-container-instances

I have a python app that uses around 15 pip libraries.
It also requires Azure Storage as it creates files.
I'd like to publish this app to Azure Functions. How do I do this?
How does Azure Function manage all the python libraries that I need?
I can't seem to find any sample code.

My code is basically like this:

```
import libA
import libB
import libC

def function1(...):
    Commands-For-Function1

def function2(...):
    Commands-For-Function2

def function3(...):
    Commands-For-Function3

function1(param1, param2).. # Execution
```

But with Azure function apps, it looks for an **init** function. How would I integrate my function into an azure function?

Also, would Azure Container Instances not be a better solution? I'd just have to containerise my solution and publish it.

Thanks

Comment: We have had the same problem. We are looking into [Azure container apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-apps/). Since we didn't want to change our code too much and Azure Functions requires this.

Comment: what do you mean? you mean a web app using a container?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions Python Project has some default folder structure recommended by Microsoft:

[image]

Whatever the dependencies, **libraries** and the shared function code, you can place in the shared code folder which is imported as modules in the main function `_init_.py` file.

You can import all the **packages**/**libraries**/methods derived in the normal class files into Azure Functions Python using the import keyword (absolute and relative references):

```py
from shared_code import my_first_helper_function #(absolute)
```

```py
import shared_code.my_second_helper_function #(absolute)
```

```py
from . import example #(relative)
```

Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=asgi,azurecli-linux,application-level#folder-structure) for more information.